# Video Thumbnails in Xamarin Forms

Tags: plugins, xamarin.forms, camera, video-thumbnails

Is there a way to retrieve a thumbnail of a video using Xamarin Forms?

I use the Xam.Plugin.Media plugin to take and pick videos and save them to a specific location. Is it possible to save a thumbnail of the video as well?

//Pick a Video

private async void BtnPick_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

```
        try
        {
            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickVideoAsync();
            if (file == null)
                return;
            await StoreVideos(file.GetStream());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

//Take Video

```
    private async void BtnTake_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakeVideoAsync(new StoreVideoOptions

        {
            Name = "video.mp4",
            Directory = "DefaultVideos",
        });
        await StoreVideos(file.GetStream());

        if (file == null)
            return;
    }

    public async Task<string> StoreVideos(Stream videoStream)
    {
        var storageVideo = await new FirebaseStorage("adam-00000.appspot.com")
            .Child("ProfileVideos")
            .Child(App.UserID + "-" + App.VideoName + ".mp4")

            .PutAsync(videoStream);

        string imgurl = storageVideo;
        return imgurl;
    }
```

I'm looking to grab the thumbnail of the video, save it and then upload it to Firebase.

Comment: You can use the dependence server to achieve it, you can create video thumbnails by the `ThumbnailUtils.CreateVideoThumbnailAsync(String, ThumbnailKind) Method` In the android platfrom. there is link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.media.thumbnailutils?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9

Comment: I am new to Xamarin Forms. Where do I put this ?[Android.Runtime.Register("android/media/ThumbnailUtils", ApiSince=8, DoNotGenerateAcw=true)]
public class ThumbnailUtils : Java.Lang.Object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not put `[Android.Runtime.Register("android/media/ThumbnailUtils", ApiSince=8, DoNotGenerateAcw=true)] public class ThumbnailUtils : Java.Lang.Objec` in you code, you just add this `using Android.Media;` in your code, Then call this `ThumbnailUtils.CreateVideoThumbnail(filePath,kind);` method to create Thumbnail of video like this link.https://stackoverflow.com/a/44304943/10627299

Note:This method is just suitable for the android platform, If you use Forms, you should achieve it with dependence service.

Comment: Thanks, with this now I have learnt how to use the dependency service, and should open up a lot of areas for me.